# How to use InvalidPluginExecutionException in UCI

Tags: dynamics-crm, uci

I use Mscrm 365 on-premise, in my last version (2016) there was a use in InvalidPluginExecutionException function to show the user an error.

In 365 I get the error but not the text I wrote, example in the image.
How can I use the  InvalidPluginExecutionException like before and show a message to the user ? if I can't is there an other way or function that I can use ?

[image]

Comment: Is this OOB WF, plugin, Biz rule ? Are you seeing this even in your custom code ?

Comment: @ArunVinoth-MVP there is a message I used to get (in the pic mark under the black line) but now I get it with all the stack info

Comment: So you are seeing more information than what you expect ? And it’s unnecessary for end user I agree

Comment: yes, in a past code there was a use in InvalidPluginExecutionException as alert in some cases..

Comment: So you’re not seeing your custom text, rather only this stack trace in exception alert ? Did you check in multiple plugins or just a plain vanilla plugin step to see the behavior, since this could be some other exception bubbling up instead of your throw. :(